# iOS table view with custom prototype cell in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a custom prototype reusable cell, but I can't drag and drop label, UIImageView or anything in my prototype, What am I doing wrong?

I have a ViewController, with a Title, special background and a button. In here i have a TableView, with a custom prototype cell. I need to drag some Labels, and UIIMage in here - But I can't drop it on the prototype cell.

If you need any further details just ask and I'll gladly respond

I'll look forward for your help! thanks in advance!

Comment: That's strange. How exactly are you trying to do this? Did you add a cell to your table view and then tried to drag a label to the cell?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zgxrau9l7kxy0ta/LPtt9EpqAB

There you can see my settings and that my label ain't placed in my cell :/ what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: But according the second picture, the label is on your cell. If you wanna use custom cells, don't forget to create a UITableViewCell subclass to configure the cell as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the tableview, close and open Xcode and try it again from a clear ViewController, sounds like you are doing everything ok to me, even thought this may help.

[image: STCK-19915627 on Twitpic]

Comment: AWESOME THANKS!!!!!!!!! 
IT works!

I forgot to drag a table cell, I used a prototype cell counter ( up in the prototype cell field in right upper corner)
Thanks a lot you helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell.

Choose the Attributes Inspector.

Change the Table View Cell's Style to Custom.

[image: Change Cell Style to Custom]

Comment: Hello Phil, I already did put it on Custom, but still it aint working,
:( any other suggestions?